# will it be rejected by MAS to open Safari or other apps with NSTask and open command

Tags: macos, applescript, nstask, mac-app-store, appstore-sandbox

I'll open Safari, other system apps and third-party apps with codes like:

```
let task = NSTask()
task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/open"
task.arguments = ["Safari"]
task.launch()
```

will it be rejected by MAS review?

I know there is recommended way by Apple which leverages Apple Script and com.apple.security.scripting-targets. But it's so weak now.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of launch options are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the recommended way to launch applications is

```
NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().launchApplication("Safari")
```

or – more sophisticated

```
let sharedWorkspace = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace()
if let safariURL = sharedWorkspace.URLForApplicationWithBundleIdentifier("com.apple.safari") {
    try? sharedWorkspace.launchApplicationAtURL(safariURL, options: NSWorkspaceLaunchOptions(), configuration: [:])
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. where can i find configuration/launch arguments for applications like TextEdit, Safari? I searched but got nothing helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Even more sophisticated you may use launch services LSOpenFromURLSpec as described [in the reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCConcepts/LSCConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000999-CH202-BABBJHID). Pass [launchs options](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/LSLaunchFlags) in the specs array.

```
LSLaunchURLSpec inLaunchSpec;

inLaunchSpec.appURL = (__bridge CFURLRef) urlOfAppToOpen;
inLaunchSpec.itemURLs =  (__bridge CFArrayRef) (arrayOfurlsOfFilesToOpenWithApp);
inLaunchSpec.passThruParams = NULL;
inLaunchSpec.launchFlags = kLSLaunchDefaults;
inLaunchSpec.asyncRefCon = NULL;

CFURLRef outLaunchedURL;
OSStatus diditOpen = LSOpenFromURLSpec (
                                        &inLaunchSpec,
                                        &outLaunchedURL
                                        );
```

Comment: @guoleii did this answer help you? if yes, would you like to accept it?